# How do I retrieve errors which occured during execution of the trace commandPrefix

Tags: tcl

The trace documentation states that "If an error occurs while executing the commandPrefix, then the command name as a whole will return that same error."  However, I do not see the error when I execute the code below, which has a faulty command prefix.  How do I get this error information?

```
proc a args { puts hello }
proc b args { bad stuff }
trace add execution a leave b
a
```

I just get "hello"

Comment: Probably related: [catch leave trace regression](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3608676&group_id=10894&atid=110894)

Comment: Not “probably”; it's exactly that bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the `hello` is *printed* by the procedure, not *returned* by it. Execution traces don't trap printed output. (You can trap printed output in Tcl 8.6 by layering a transform on the `stdout` channel, but that's a totally different thing.)

So, let's change your code to this instead, which is much clearer about what is happening:

```
proc a args { puts hello; return flimgargle }
proc b args { puts "b:$args"; error "bad stuff" }
trace add execution a leave b
puts [a]
```

With tclsh8.4 and tclsh8.6 (built off the current development HEAD), I get this (with the last line being an error message):

```
hello
b:a 0 flimgargle leave
bad stuff
```

With tclsh8.5 (specifically 8.5.2), I get this:

```
hello
b:a 0 flimgargle leave
flimgargle
```

This is [a known bug](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3608676&group_id=10894&atid=110894) in tclsh8.5 (due to changes in how traces are implemented between 8.5 and 8.4) that is fixed in the next release (8.5.14). We're just testing release candidates for that, so the fix should be widely available Real Soon.

Comment: I tried tclsh8.4 and I do see the error message, and $errorInfo is set properly, and the error stack is displayed properly.